# AWS Spot Instance T2 Unlimited

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to request a spot instance from AWS EC2, and I have T2 Unlimited Turned off:

[image]

However, when launching I get the following error:

```
Error
The r4.large instance type does not support T2 Unlimited.
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: It cant be a bug in console, try to add request from CLI or contact support

Comment: *can - sorry for typo

Comment: As it happens the "basic" support plan only gives support for account and billing issues, let me try on their forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `Template or default value` instead of `Disable`.

However, if the template has a value configured for **T2/T3 Unlimited**, then it will use that value instead of a Default value. This will prohibit the launch.

So, it appears you will need to **change the template** to `Don't include in launch template` if the template is going to be used by an instance type other than T2/T3.

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow, I am using the default r4.large, but don't see the option to set Don't include in launch template, could you please advise?

Comment: When creating a Launch Template, you can set a value for **T2/T3 Unlimited** (at the bottom, under _Advanced Details_). The options are Enable, Disable and "Don't include in launch template". You will need to edit the Launch Template to set the value to "Don't include in launch template", otherwise the template will not work with a non-T2/T3 instance.